# Name of a Sobolev/Poincare type inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

It is a basic analysis exercise to verify that for $u \colon [0,1] \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$, if $u(0,t) = 0$ for all $t$, then
$$ ||u(\cdot,t)||_\infty \leq ||u_x(\cdot,t)||_2,$$
where the norms are taken over space (after fixing time). Is there a name for this inequality?

EDIT: the proof is
\begin{align*}
|u(x,t)|
&= \left| \int_0^x u_y(y,t) dy \right| \\
&\leq \int_0^x \left| u_y(y,t) \right| dy \\
&\leq \int_0^1 \left| u_x(x,t) \right| dx \\
&\leq \left( \int_0^1 1^2 dy \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_0^1 |u_x(x,t)|^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \\
&=  \left( \int_0^1 |u_x(x,t)|^2 dx \right)^{1/2} 
\end{align*}

Any references would be helpful.

Comment: If u(x,t)=x e^{-kt} then \|u\|_\infty=1 but \|u_x\|_2=1/\sqrt{2k}. Am I misunderstanding the claim?

Comment: Can you tex that? And we are fixing time when taking the norms

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying, you can ignore my previous comment. It seems that the second variable isn't really relevant then; you could just as well state the inequality for u:[0,1]->R with u(0)=0.

Comment: Yes, it is irrelevant for this particular problem, though the PDE I am working with has a time component.